# Relation between length and font-size of a string and width of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, width, font-size

I've a field in a database, this field has a maximum length, and I want to set a textbox to the appropriate width. I'm creating the textboxes in runtime. How can I calculate the value of width property?

For example, if I have a field nvarchar(5) named IDClient, and the font-Size is 13, I want to create a texbox with a width enough to write 5 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe should use [TextRenderer.MeasureText(string, font)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx).

Here a little sample which should might help you

```
        //Get this value from somewhere...
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        int maxWidth = 10;
        int extraSpace = 3;

        //Create sample string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxWidth);
        sb.Append('w', maxWidth);

        //Measure text 
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), textBox.Font);

        //Set width of TextBox to needed width
        textBox.Width = size.Width + extraSpace;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify

input type='text' size='5' width='w' ........>

You can calculate w=num_characters * k.
Where k is constant. First keep k = 15.
And then do hit and trial until u find the best fit.

Comment: Also you must keep in mind, that until font is a courier type. You must calculate k by width of 'w'. Because it is the widest alphabet.

Comment: Thanks!! Ok, lets supose that I find the perfect K value for size = 5. What happens when the font size changes? The problem is that I only know the font size in runtime. I need some algorithm that calc W using size and lenght of the string.

Comment: I know its not the best approach. But you can make it:

w= num_chars * font_size * k;
and then find k.

Since width will be directly proportional to the font size (in linear fashion). THere will exist a valid value of k for a font face.